# "transition: opacity 1" for cached image doesn't work. How do i replace 2 "img" elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I make smooth background change with replacing one `<img>` element to another. Everything goes fine, but if I replace to image that already has been used, transition doesn't work.

Click on "Background 2". It replaces perfect.
Click on "Background 3". Same result.
Click on "Background 1" or "Background 2". It crashes

[There is my code on Codepen](https://codepen.io/user5739/pen/KKPMzWv)
Also original page you can see below:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background change</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <style>
      /* Nothing important */
      #background { z-index: -100; }
      .background {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        object-fit: cover;
        position: fixed;
        transition: opacity 2s;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function setBackground(url) {
        // --- Do not change if it is the same image
        if (background.getAttribute("src") == url) return
        // Create new background image elememt
        let newBackground = document.createElement("img")
        newBackground.id = "newBackground"
        newBackground.className = "background"
        // --- Place new img tag behind old img tag
        newBackground.style.opacity = 0
        newBackground.style.zIndex = -90
        newBackground.src = url
        // --- Insert img tag in DOM
        background.after(newBackground)
        // --- Start transition
        function start(){ console.log("start"); newBackground.style.opacity = 1 }
        // --- Runs after transition
        function end(){
          console.log("end")
          // --- Remove old img from DOM
          background.remove()
          // --- Set standard values for 'id' and 'z-index'
          newBackground.id = "background"
          newBackground.style.zIndex = -100
          // --- Assign 'background' to new img element (for future usage)
          background = document.getElementById("background")
        }
        newBackground.addEventListener("transitionend", end)
        // --- Start transition if img is cached
        // --- Maybe here is an error?
        if (newBackground.complete) start()
        else newBackground.addEventListener("load", start)
      }

      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        background = document.getElementById("background")
      })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="background" class="background" src="https://i.imgur.com/6IjDFqg.jpg"/>
    <button onclick="setBackground('https://i.imgur.com/6IjDFqg.jpg')">Background 1</button><br/>
    <button onclick="setBackground('https://i.imgur.com/Ai5Zbq1.jpg')">Background 2</button><br/>
    <button onclick="setBackground('https://i.imgur.com/9jHOYe9.jpg')">Background 3</button><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to replace two `<img>` tags with transition in pure JavaScript? Maybe there is some more simple way. Or I just do something wrong.

(Sorry for my English)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had enough time to look into it fully, but looks like the transitionend event doesn't get fired when the complete flag is set, so then the end function is never called to change the opacity.

If you change these two lines:

```
    if (newBackground.complete) start()
    else newBackground.addEventListener("load", start)
```

into this

```
    newBackground.addEventListener("load", start)
```

then it will consistently do the transitions (providing you wait until

Comment: I've changed [CodePen](https://codepen.io/user5739/pen/KKPMzWv), but it still doen't work properly